# Terraform Helm Release Error: Missing CRDs for Jaeger Operator on AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-helm, jaeger

I'm attempting to set up the Jaeger Operator on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) using Terraform. I've encountered an issue while deploying the Helm release for the Jaeger Operator. The error message I'm receiving indicates that there are missing Custom Resource Definitions (CRDs) required for the Jaeger Operator to function, particularly related to cert-manager.

**Terraform code:**

```
resource "helm_release" "jaeger_operator" {
  name       = "jaeger-operator"
  repository = "https://jaegertracing.github.io/helm-charts"
  chart      = "jaeger-operator"
  version    = "2.46.2"

  depends_on = [helm_release.elastic]
}
```

**Error Message:**

```
│ Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: [resource mapping not found for name: "jaeger-operator-service-cert" namespace: "default" from "": no matches for kind "Certificate" in version "cert-manager.io/v1"
│ ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "selfsigned-issuer" namespace: "default" from "": no matches for kind "Issuer" in version "cert-manager.io/v1"
│ ensure CRDs are installed first]
│ 
│   with module.kube.helm_release.jaeger_operator,
│   on ../modules/kube/jaeger.tf line 1, in resource "helm_release" "jaeger_operator":
│    1: resource "helm_release" "jaeger_operator" {
│
```

I've tried searching for solutions online, but I haven't been able to find a clear resolution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I fix this issue with this terraform code:

```
resource "helm_release" "cert_manager" {
  name       = "cert-manager"
  repository = "https://charts.jetstack.io"
  chart      = "cert-manager"
  version    = "v1.7.1"
  namespace  = var.namespace

  set {
    name  = "installCRDs"
    value = "true"
  }
}
```